# Do separate functions in a Node.js Azure Functions app share memory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-functions

As an example, lets say that an Azure Functions App contains a shared module which provides a global connection pool to some resource:

```js
// connection-pool.js
const pool = /* initialize pool ... */

exports.getPool = () => pool
```

And two functions within the FunctionsApp that make use of the shared connection pool module:

```js
// fn1/index.js
const pool = require('../connection-pool').getPool()

module.exports = async function (ctx, req) {
  // Do something...
}
```

```js
// fn2/index.js
const pool = require('../connection-pool').getPool()

module.exports = async function (ctx, req) {
  // Do something...
}
```

Will there exist 1 or 2 pools within a single instance of the Functions App at runtime?

Comment: Check this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections

Comment: Thanks, but I've already looked there and there was no clear answer, which is why I've asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worker for a language starts along with the host in each instance and within the same instance, the loaded modules are in the same memory space.

Do note that as your function scales, each instance would have its own memory space. So, this won't work for cases where you want to store any state.